# Process is NOT integrated but autocorrelated. Can I use linear regression models?

Tags: autocorrelation, stationarity, unit-root

I'm carrying out a stationarity analysis over a process Y that looks like this:

[image]

From the autocorrelation function the process doesn't look strictly stationary since the decay is quite low, even if it dies out after around 15 lags:

[image]

However if I test for unit roots i can reject the null of non-stationarity:

```r
    Augmented Dickey-Fuller Test

data:  d4lfr
Dickey-Fuller = -3.7151, Lag order = 6, p-value = 0.0249
alternative hypothesis: stationary
```

My interpretation of this would be the following (I am open to discussion):
The process is NOT integrated but exhibits strong autocorrelation (maybe some sort of long memory process?). Therefore is not strictly stationary either, since conditional distributions change over different time horizons.

Now how do I account for this in the context of a linear model? Can I use the series in a regression like Y = aX + e without bias? It is enough to find a good specification and/or to correct for serial correlation or it's better to resort to differencing/filtering the series? I'm just not sure about the best course of action here.

Comment: Strong autocorrelation is compatible with stationarity. To reject stationarity you would need some other argument.

Comment: @RichardHardy thank you. So I can use the variable in a linear model without fearing bias?

Comment: from my basic econometrics course (taken some years ago!), I recall that in a time series linear regression one has to be careful about cointegration.

Comment: @utobi thank you. In fact my issue is precisely this: if the series WERE integrated, I am supposed to difference it. But the series is NOT integrated (to my understanding). It's just very persistent so that its conditional mean is changing over the sample. So I'm not sure on how to deal with that